# If value is 0 then return empty string in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to return empty string when some value is "0", but from HTML page using angularJs?

If I have something like this:

```
<p>External | Year of Birth: {{profileCtrl.person.year}}</p>
```

Can I write some expression right there that will check the value for `profileCtrl.person.year`? If the value is "0" then return empty string, else return value of `profileCtrl.person.year`.

Something like this is very easy to do in languages like C#, but since I am very new to Angular I was unable to find out if this technology has a power to do such thing?

Can someone help me out with this maybe?

Comment: did you try `{{profileCtrl.person.year === 0?"":profileCtrl.person.year}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{{profileCtrl.person.year === 0 ? "" : profileCtrl.person.year}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator to achieve this;

```
{{profileCtrl.person.year === 0 ? "" : profileCtrl.person.year}}
```

This basically says, if it's 0 provide "", else provide the year.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ternary operator `?`:

```
{{ profileCtrl.person.year === 0 ? "" : profileCtrl.person.year }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), which uses the second value if the first value is falsy.

```
<p>External | Year of Birth: {{profileCtrl.person.year || ""}}</p>
```

Another solution could be to show the wole part, with `ng-show` attribute and a truthy value. On a falsy value the part is hidden.

```
<p ng-show="profileCtrl.person.year">External | Year of Birth: {{profileCtrl.person.year}}</p>
```

Comment: This will give blank string for all falsey values. `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`

Comment: @Rajesh, yes, it does. and it is better than the real falsey value for a web output. but op expects only zero value, this is converted to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator:

```
<p>External | Year of Birth: {{profileCtrl.person.year !== 0 ? profileCtrl.person.year : ""}}</p>
```

Another approach might be (haven't checked):

```
<p>External | Year of Birth: {{profileCtrl.person.year || ""}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter in your code for return empty

```
//js file
app.filter("filterName",function(){
    return function(input){
           switch(input){
           case 0:
           return "";
    }
});

<!-- html page -->
{{input | filterName}}
```